# How to install mongodb for windows 10

Tags: mongodb, mongodb-query

I am trying to install mongodb in my windows 10 system.But i am getting this error.I have downloaded mangodb 4.2.8 as a zip and i tried to install.Also i have tried with mongodb.exe file but no use same error getting again.So i am not able to install. If anyone knows please help me to find solution.

Getting this error message on installation:

[image]

```
C:\Users\admin\Downloads\mongodb-win32-x86_64-2012plus-4.2.8\mongodb-win32-x86_64-2012plus-4.2.8\bin>mongod
2020-07-11T12:54:50.108+0530 I  CONTROL  [main] Automatically disabling TLS 1.0, to force-enable TLS 1.0 specify --sslDisabledProtocols 'none'
2020-07-11T12:54:50.473+0530 W  ASIO     [main] No TransportLayer configured during NetworkInterface startup
2020-07-11T12:54:50.473+0530 I  CONTROL  [initandlisten] MongoDB starting : pid=7924 port=27017 dbpath=C:\data\db\ 64-bit host=DESKTOP-UO2CITD
2020-07-11T12:54:50.473+0530 I  CONTROL  [initandlisten] targetMinOS: Windows 7/Windows Server 2008 R2
2020-07-11T12:54:50.473+0530 I  CONTROL  [initandlisten] db version v4.2.8
2020-07-11T12:54:50.474+0530 I  CONTROL  [initandlisten] git version: 43d25964249164d76d5e04dd6cf38f6111e21f5f
2020-07-11T12:54:50.474+0530 I  CONTROL  [initandlisten] allocator: tcmalloc
2020-07-11T12:54:50.474+0530 I  CONTROL  [initandlisten] modules: none
2020-07-11T12:54:50.474+0530 I  CONTROL  [initandlisten] build environment:
2020-07-11T12:54:50.474+0530 I  CONTROL  [initandlisten]     distmod: 2012plus
2020-07-11T12:54:50.474+0530 I  CONTROL  [initandlisten]     distarch: x86_64
2020-07-11T12:54:50.474+0530 I  CONTROL  [initandlisten]     target_arch: x86_64
2020-07-11T12:54:50.474+0530 I  CONTROL  [initandlisten] options: {}
2020-07-11T12:54:50.476+0530 I  STORAGE  [initandlisten] wiredtiger_open config: create,cache_size=7649M,cache_overflow=(file_max=0M),session_max=33000,eviction=(threads_min=4,threads_max=4),config_base=false,statistics=(fast),log=(enabled=true,archive=true,path=journal,compressor=snappy),file_manager=(close_idle_time=100000,close_scan_interval=10,close_handle_minimum=250),statistics_log=(wait=0),verbose=[recovery_progress,checkpoint_progress],
2020-07-11T12:54:50.508+0530 I  STORAGE  [initandlisten] WiredTiger message [1594452290:507927][7924:140721296465488], txn-recover: Set global recovery timestamp: (0, 0)
2020-07-11T12:54:50.522+0530 I  RECOVERY [initandlisten] WiredTiger recoveryTimestamp. Ts: Timestamp(0, 0)
2020-07-11T12:54:50.544+0530 I  STORAGE  [initandlisten] Timestamp monitor starting
2020-07-11T12:54:50.549+0530 I  CONTROL  [initandlisten]
2020-07-11T12:54:50.549+0530 I  CONTROL  [initandlisten] ** WARNING: Access control is not enabled for the database.
2020-07-11T12:54:50.549+0530 I  CONTROL  [initandlisten] **          Read and write access to data and configuration is unrestricted.
2020-07-11T12:54:50.549+0530 I  CONTROL  [initandlisten]
2020-07-11T12:54:50.550+0530 I  CONTROL  [initandlisten] ** WARNING: This server is bound to localhost.
2020-07-11T12:54:50.550+0530 I  CONTROL  [initandlisten] **          Remote systems will be unable to connect to this server.
2020-07-11T12:54:50.550+0530 I  CONTROL  [initandlisten] **          Start the server with --bind_ip <address> to specify which IP
2020-07-11T12:54:50.550+0530 I  CONTROL  [initandlisten] **          addresses it should serve responses from, or with --bind_ip_all to
2020-07-11T12:54:50.550+0530 I  CONTROL  [initandlisten] **          bind to all interfaces. If this behavior is desired, start the
2020-07-11T12:54:50.550+0530 I  CONTROL  [initandlisten] **          server with --bind_ip 127.0.0.1 to disable this warning.
2020-07-11T12:54:50.551+0530 I  CONTROL  [initandlisten]
2020-07-11T12:54:50.551+0530 I  STORAGE  [initandlisten] createCollection: admin.system.version with provided UUID: 8ba4a1dc-d7a9-4e11-b1cf-696eff95f3b6 and options: { uuid: UUID("8ba4a1dc-d7a9-4e11-b1cf-696eff95f3b6") }
2020-07-11T12:54:50.571+0530 I  INDEX    [initandlisten] index build: done building index _id_ on ns admin.system.version
2020-07-11T12:54:50.572+0530 I  SHARDING [initandlisten] Marking collection admin.system.version as collection version: <unsharded>
2020-07-11T12:54:50.573+0530 I  COMMAND  [initandlisten] setting featureCompatibilityVersion to 4.2
2020-07-11T12:54:50.575+0530 I  SHARDING [initandlisten] Marking collection local.system.replset as collection version: <unsharded>
2020-07-11T12:54:50.576+0530 I  STORAGE  [initandlisten] Flow Control is enabled on this deployment.
2020-07-11T12:54:50.576+0530 I  SHARDING [initandlisten] Marking collection admin.system.roles as collection version: <unsharded>
2020-07-11T12:54:50.578+0530 I  STORAGE  [initandlisten] createCollection: local.startup_log with generated UUID: 16bb8a73-7b9f-4c54-a26f-3eb9272bdee3 and options: { capped: true, size: 10485760 }
2020-07-11T12:54:50.594+0530 I  INDEX    [initandlisten] index build: done building index _id_ on ns local.startup_log
2020-07-11T12:54:50.595+0530 I  SHARDING [initandlisten] Marking collection local.startup_log as collection version: <unsharded>
2020-07-11T12:54:50.919+0530 I  FTDC     [initandlisten] Initializing full-time diagnostic data capture with directory 'C:/data/db/diagnostic.data'
2020-07-11T12:54:50.922+0530 I  SHARDING [LogicalSessionCacheRefresh] Marking collection config.system.sessions as collection version: <unsharded>
2020-07-11T12:54:50.922+0530 I  CONTROL  [LogicalSessionCacheReap] Sessions collection is not set up; waiting until next sessions reap interval: config.system.sessions does not exist
2020-07-11T12:54:50.922+0530 I  STORAGE  [LogicalSessionCacheRefresh] createCollection: config.system.sessions with provided UUID: e11d499e-d0a8-47f9-baa8-3e007f3fa5af and options: { uuid: UUID("e11d499e-d0a8-47f9-baa8-3e007f3fa5af") }
2020-07-11T12:54:50.923+0530 I  NETWORK  [listener] Listening on 127.0.0.1
2020-07-11T12:54:50.923+0530 I  NETWORK  [listener] waiting for connections on port 27017
2020-07-11T12:54:50.934+0530 I  INDEX    [LogicalSessionCacheRefresh] index build: done building index _id_ on ns config.system.sessions
2020-07-11T12:54:50.949+0530 I  INDEX    [LogicalSessionCacheRefresh] index build: starting on config.system.sessions properties: { v: 2, key: { lastUse: 1 }, name: "lsidTTLIndex", ns: "config.system.sessions", expireAfterSeconds: 1800 } using method: Hybrid
2020-07-11T12:54:50.949+0530 I  INDEX    [LogicalSessionCacheRefresh] build may temporarily use up to 200 megabytes of RAM
2020-07-11T12:54:50.950+0530 I  INDEX    [LogicalSessionCacheRefresh] index build: collection scan done. scanned 0 total records in 0 seconds
2020-07-11T12:54:50.952+0530 I  INDEX    [LogicalSessionCacheRefresh] index build: inserted 0 keys from external sorter into index in 0 seconds
2020-07-11T12:54:50.955+0530 I  INDEX    [LogicalSessionCacheRefresh] index build: done building index lsidTTLIndex on ns config.system.sessions
2020-07-11T12:54:51.005+0530 I  SHARDING [ftdc] Marking collection local.oplog.rs as collection version: <unsharded>
2020-07-11T12:55:12.007+0530 W  FTDC     [ftdc] Uncaught exception in 'FileRenameFailed: The process cannot access the file because it is being used by another process' in full-time diagnostic data capture subsystem. Shutting down the full-time diagnostic data capture subsystem.
2020-07-11T12:56:50.562+0530 E  STORAGE  [WTCheckpointThread] WiredTiger error (16) [1594452410:562012][7924:140721296465488], file:WiredTiger.wt, WT_SESSION.checkpoint: __win_fs_rename, 125: C:\data\db\\WiredTiger.turtle.set to C:\data\db\\WiredTiger.turtle: file-rename: MoveFileExW: The process cannot access the file because it is being used by another process.
: Resource device Raw: [1594452410:562012][7924:140721296465488], file:WiredTiger.wt, WT_SESSION.checkpoint: __win_fs_rename, 125: C:\data\db\\WiredTiger.turtle.set to C:\data\db\\WiredTiger.turtle: file-rename: MoveFileExW: The process cannot access the file because it is being used by another process.
: Resource device
2020-07-11T12:56:50.565+0530 E  STORAGE  [WTCheckpointThread] WiredTiger error (16) [1594452410:565480][7924:140721296465488], file:WiredTiger.wt, WT_SESSION.checkpoint: __win_fs_remove, 81: C:\data\db\\WiredTiger.turtle.set: file-remove: DeleteFileW: The process cannot access the file because it is being used by another process.
: Resource device Raw: [1594452410:565480][7924:140721296465488], file:WiredTiger.wt, WT_SESSION.checkpoint: __win_fs_remove, 81: C:\data\db\\WiredTiger.turtle.set: file-remove: DeleteFileW: The process cannot access the file because it is being used by another process.
: Resource device
2020-07-11T12:56:50.565+0530 E  STORAGE  [WTCheckpointThread] WiredTiger error (16) [1594452410:565480][7924:140721296465488], file:WiredTiger.wt, WT_SESSION.checkpoint: __wt_turtle_update, 395: WiredTiger.turtle: fatal turtle file update error: Resource device Raw: [1594452410:565480][7924:140721296465488], file:WiredTiger.wt, WT_SESSION.checkpoint: __wt_turtle_update, 395: WiredTiger.turtle: fatal turtle file update error: Resource device
2020-07-11T12:56:50.566+0530 E  STORAGE  [WTCheckpointThread] WiredTiger error (-31804) [1594452410:565480][7924:140721296465488], file:WiredTiger.wt, WT_SESSION.checkpoint: __wt_panic, 490: the process must exit and restart: WT_PANIC: WiredTiger library panic Raw: [1594452410:565480][7924:140721296465488], file:WiredTiger.wt, WT_SESSION.checkpoint: __wt_panic, 490: the process must exit and restart: WT_PANIC: WiredTiger library panic
2020-07-11T12:56:50.566+0530 F  -        [WTCheckpointThread] Fatal Assertion 50853 at src\mongo\db\storage\wiredtiger\wiredtiger_util.cpp 414
2020-07-11T12:56:50.566+0530 F  -        [WTCheckpointThread]

***aborting after fassert() failure 

2020-07-11T12:56:51.290+0530 F  -        [WTCheckpointThread] Got signal: 22 (SIGABRT).
mongod.exe    ...\src\mongo\util\stacktrace_windows.cpp(246)                                                                       mongo::printStackTrace+0x43
mongod.exe    ...\src\mongo\util\signal_handlers_synchronous.cpp(241)                                                              mongo::`anonymous namespace'::abruptQuit+0x81
ucrtbase.dll                                                                                                                       raise+0x1dd
ucrtbase.dll                                                                                                                       abort+0x31
mongod.exe    ...\src\mongo\util\assert_util.cpp(145)                                                                              mongo::fassertFailedWithLocation+0xd6
mongod.exe    ...\src\mongo\db\storage\wiredtiger\wiredtiger_util.cpp(414)                                                         mongo::`anonymous namespace'::mdb_handle_error_with_startup_suppression+0x2d1
mongod.exe    ...\src\third_party\wiredtiger\src\support\err.c(263)                                                                __eventv+0x38d
mongod.exe    ...\src\third_party\wiredtiger\src\support\err.c(312)                                                                __wt_err_func+0x2a
mongod.exe    ...\src\third_party\wiredtiger\src\support\err.c(507)                                                                __wt_panic+0x40
mongod.exe    ...\src\third_party\wiredtiger\src\meta\meta_turtle.c(395)                                                           __wt_turtle_update+0x38b
mongod.exe    ...\src\third_party\wiredtiger\src\meta\meta_table.c(211)                                                            __wt_metadata_update+0x35b
mongod.exe    ...\src\third_party\wiredtiger\src\meta\meta_ckpt.c(208)                                                             __ckpt_set+0xf1
mongod.exe    ...\src\third_party\wiredtiger\src\meta\meta_ckpt.c(814)                                                             __wt_meta_ckptlist_set+0x3fa
mongod.exe    ...\src\third_party\wiredtiger\src\txn\txn_ckpt.c(1605)                                                              __checkpoint_tree+0x1e0
mongod.exe    ...\src\third_party\wiredtiger\src\txn\txn_ckpt.c(1738)                                                              __wt_checkpoint+0x94
mongod.exe    ...\src\third_party\wiredtiger\src\txn\txn_ckpt.c(911)                                                               __txn_checkpoint+0x70a
mongod.exe    ...\src\third_party\wiredtiger\src\txn\txn_ckpt.c(1043)                                                              __txn_checkpoint_wrapper+0x189
mongod.exe    ...\src\third_party\wiredtiger\src\txn\txn_ckpt.c(1101)                                                              __wt_txn_checkpoint+0x112
mongod.exe    ...\src\third_party\wiredtiger\src\session\session_api.c(1962)                                                       __session_checkpoint+0x3bc
mongod.exe    ...\src\mongo\db\storage\wiredtiger\wiredtiger_kv_engine.cpp(359)                                                    mongo::WiredTigerKVEngine::WiredTigerCheckpointThread::run+0x3f6
mongod.exe    ...\src\mongo\util\background.cpp(154)                                                                               mongo::BackgroundJob::jobBody+0x145
mongod.exe    c:\program files (x86)\microsoft visual studio\2017\professional\vc\tools\msvc\14.16.27023\include\thr\xthread(230)  std::_LaunchPad<std::unique_ptr<std::tuple<<lambda_e94772a372767cbd7bebbcdd24044cf3> >,std::default_delete<std::tuple<<lambda_e94772a372767cbd7bebbcdd24044cf3> > > > >::_Go+0x6d
mongod.exe    c:\program files (x86)\microsoft visual studio\2017\professional\vc\tools\msvc\14.16.27023\include\thr\xthread(209)  std::_Pad::_Call_func+0x9
ucrtbase.dll                                                                                                                       beginthreadex+0x142
KERNEL32.DLL                                                                                                                       BaseThreadInitThunk+0x14
2020-07-11T12:56:51.297+0530 F  CONTROL  [WTCheckpointThread] *** unhandled exception 0x0000000E at 0x00007FFC391CA799, terminating
2020-07-11T12:56:51.297+0530 F  CONTROL  [WTCheckpointThread] *** stack trace for unhandled exception:
2020-07-11T12:56:51.305+0530 I  -        [WTCheckpointThread] KERNELBASE.dll                                                                                                                       RaiseException+0x69
mongod.exe      ...\src\mongo\util\signal_handlers_synchronous.cpp(243)                                                              mongo::`anonymous namespace'::abruptQuit+0x9e
ucrtbase.dll                                                                                                                         raise+0x1dd
ucrtbase.dll                                                                                                                         abort+0x31
mongod.exe      ...\src\mongo\util\assert_util.cpp(145)                                                                              mongo::fassertFailedWithLocation+0xd6
mongod.exe      ...\src\mongo\db\storage\wiredtiger\wiredtiger_util.cpp(414)                                                         mongo::`anonymous namespace'::mdb_handle_error_with_startup_suppression+0x2d1
mongod.exe      ...\src\third_party\wiredtiger\src\support\err.c(263)                                                                __eventv+0x38d
mongod.exe      ...\src\third_party\wiredtiger\src\support\err.c(312)                                                                __wt_err_func+0x2a
mongod.exe      ...\src\third_party\wiredtiger\src\support\err.c(507)                                                                __wt_panic+0x40
mongod.exe      ...\src\third_party\wiredtiger\src\meta\meta_turtle.c(395)                                                           __wt_turtle_update+0x38b
mongod.exe      ...\src\third_party\wiredtiger\src\meta\meta_table.c(211)                                                            __wt_metadata_update+0x35b
mongod.exe      ...\src\third_party\wiredtiger\src\meta\meta_ckpt.c(208)                                                             __ckpt_set+0xf1
mongod.exe      ...\src\third_party\wiredtiger\src\meta\meta_ckpt.c(814)                                                             __wt_meta_ckptlist_set+0x3fa
mongod.exe      ...\src\third_party\wiredtiger\src\txn\txn_ckpt.c(1605)                                                              __checkpoint_tree+0x1e0
mongod.exe      ...\src\third_party\wiredtiger\src\txn\txn_ckpt.c(1738)                                                              __wt_checkpoint+0x94
mongod.exe      ...\src\third_party\wiredtiger\src\txn\txn_ckpt.c(911)                                                               __txn_checkpoint+0x70a
mongod.exe      ...\src\third_party\wiredtiger\src\txn\txn_ckpt.c(1043)                                                              __txn_checkpoint_wrapper+0x189
mongod.exe      ...\src\third_party\wiredtiger\src\txn\txn_ckpt.c(1101)                                                              __wt_txn_checkpoint+0x112
mongod.exe      ...\src\third_party\wiredtiger\src\session\session_api.c(1962)                                                       __session_checkpoint+0x3bc
mongod.exe      ...\src\mongo\db\storage\wiredtiger\wiredtiger_kv_engine.cpp(359)                                                    mongo::WiredTigerKVEngine::WiredTigerCheckpointThread::run+0x3f6
mongod.exe      ...\src\mongo\util\background.cpp(154)                                                                               mongo::BackgroundJob::jobBody+0x145
mongod.exe      c:\program files (x86)\microsoft visual studio\2017\professional\vc\tools\msvc\14.16.27023\include\thr\xthread(230)  std::_LaunchPad<std::unique_ptr<std::tuple<<lambda_e94772a372767cbd7bebbcdd24044cf3> >,std::default_delete<std::tuple<<lambda_e94772a372767cbd7bebbcdd24044cf3> > > > >::_Go+0x6d
mongod.exe      c:\program files (x86)\microsoft visual studio\2017\professional\vc\tools\msvc\14.16.27023\include\thr\xthread(209)  std::_Pad::_Call_func+0x9
ucrtbase.dll                                                                                                                         beginthreadex+0x142
KERNEL32.DLL                                                                                                                         BaseThreadInitThunk+0x14
2020-07-11T12:56:51.307+0530 I  CONTROL  [WTCheckpointThread] writing minidump diagnostic file C:\Users\admin\Downloads\mongodb-win32-x86_64-2012plus-4.2.8\mongodb-win32-x86_64-2012plus-4.2.8\bin\mongod.2020-07-11T07-26-51.mdmp
2020-07-11T12:56:51.459+0530 F  CONTROL  [WTCheckpointThread] *** immediate exit due to unhandled exception

C:\Users\admin\Downloads\mongodb-win32-x86_64-2012plus-4.2.8\mongodb-win32-x86_64-2012plus-4.2.8\bin>
```

Comment: Try this command in terminal `md C:\data\db\ `

Comment: You have several `The process cannot access the file because it is being used by another process` errors. Did you try to start the database more than once?

Comment: Added screenshot for installation error.Please check my question

Answer (score 0):

Have you noticed this error?

```
Resource device Raw: [1594452410:562012][7924:140721296465488], file:WiredTiger.wt, WT_SESSION.checkpoint: __win_fs_rename, 125: C:\data\db\\WiredTiger.turtle.set to C:\data\db\\WiredTiger.turtle: file-rename: MoveFileExW: The process cannot access the file because it is being used by another process.
: Resource device
2020-07-11T12:56:50.565+0530 E  STORAGE  [WTCheckpointThread] WiredTiger error (16) [1594452410:565480][7924:140721296465488], file:WiredTiger.wt, WT_SESSION.checkpoint: __win_fs_remove, 81: C:\data\db\\WiredTiger.turtle.set: file-remove: DeleteFileW: The process cannot access the file because it is being used by another process.
: Resource device Raw: [1594452410:565480][7924:140721296465488], file:WiredTiger.wt, WT_SESSION.checkpoint: __win_fs_remove, 81: C:\data\db\\WiredTiger.turtle.set: file-remove: DeleteFileW: The process cannot access the file because it is being used by another process.
```

Try to clean up the aborted installation. Remove this directory:  C:\data\db\ and try again, please

Comment: Added screenshot for installation error.Please check my question

Comment: I believe it is a Windows system error. Try to update your windows to solve the problem. You can achieve that by oppening Settings menu >> Update & security >> Windows Update.

Comment: I have installed norton antivirus..So this is issue?